# How to invoke the google api url in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to find out the city name with Latitude&langitude.

below is my error image[image].

Below is my ts file code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import  {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjsoperator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  static get parameters(){
    return [[Http]];
  }

  geolocationObj

  latitude
  longitude

  // constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public locationTracker: LocationTracker) {
  //   this.geolocationObj=this.locationTracker.startTracking();

  //   this.latitude = this.geolocationObj.coords.latitude;
  //   console.log(this.latitude);

  // }

  constructor(public navCtrl:NavController , public http:Http){

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
this.latitude=resp.coords.latitude;
this.longitude=resp.coords.longitude;
      console.log("latitude"+resp.coords.latitude);
      console.log("longitude"+resp.coords.longitude);
 console.log("latitude"+this.latitude);
      console.log("longitude"+this.longitude);

      // this.latitude=resp.coords.latitude;
      // this.longitude=resp.coords.longitude;
      var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.comapijson?latlng='+this.latitude+','+this.longitude+'&sensor=true';
     var response =this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
     console.log(response);

     return response;


    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
  }
}
```

I trying to find out the location using with Latitude&Langitude but i am getting errors..please check my code

Comment: Did you forget to inject the http to your constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didnt inject the `Http` service. You can do it by,

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export class HomePage {
  constructor(public http: Http){}
}
```

Comment: I can do that one but it is not comeing

Comment: Are you getting the same error?  Btw you are returning an ``Observable`` inside ``Promise`` , So you will have to consume it accordingly.